# Terraform creating single SG but multiple CIDR blocks

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am trying to use Terraform to create a single security group that will allow traffic for mongo on port `27017` from all my private subnets that are stored in a variable. My issue is I am unsure how this would work since I only want one SG but the foreach creates multiple - at least it did before with subnets

my variable

```
variable "subnet_numbers_private" {
  description = "Useless info"
  default     = {
    "us-east-1a" = 1
    "us-east-1b" = 2
    "us-east-1c" = 3
  }
}
```

my security group resource

```
resource "aws_security_group" "mongo" {
  for_each = var.subnet_numbers_private
  name        = "Mongo"
  description = "Allow mongo traffic"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.Main_VPC.id

  ingress {
    from_port   = 27017
    to_port     = 27017
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = [cidrsubnet(aws_vpc.Main_VPC.cidr_block, 8, each.value)]
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "Mongo-${each.key}"
  }
}
```

Currently this just provides an error that doesn't mean much to me as I don't know TF 0.12 well enough

```
Because aws_security_group.mongo has "for_each" set, its attributes must be
accessed on specific instances.

For example, to correlate with indices of a referring resource, use:
    aws_security_group.mongo[each.key]
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the answer, fourtinately for me I had missed the example in the blog post about terraform 0.12 linked below

Here is my final (working how I want) security group

```
resource "aws_security_group" "mongo" {
  name        = "Mongo"
  description = "Allow mongo traffic"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.Main_VPC.id

  ingress {
    from_port   = 27017
    to_port     = 27017
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = [
      for num in var.private_subnet_numbers:
      cidrsubnet(aws_vpc.Main_VPC.cidr_block, 8, num)
    ]
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "Mongo"
  }
}
```

Link to blog post about foreach - https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/hashicorp-terraform-0-12-preview-for-and-for-each/